# Antiderivative of a linear matrix expression

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ be a function that takes an $n\times m$ matrix $X$ and maps it to the real line. Suppose that the derivative of $f$ with respect to one element $X_{ij}$ is
$$
\frac{df}{dX_{ij}}=a^\top XE1_jb_i
$$
where $a$ is an $n\times 1$ vector, $E$ is an $m\times m$ positive definite matrix, $b$ is an $n\times 1$ vector, and $1_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

My question is: What is $f$? Does such a $f$ even exist?

If $a=b$, I believe that the answer is

$$f=\frac{1}{2}a^\top X E X^\top a+\text{cte},$$

but I can't seem to generalize this result. Similarly, if $m=n=1$ it is trivial to find $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\rank{\mathrm{rank}}$
$\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$\def\inv#1{\left( #1 \right)^{-1}}$
$\def\nspace#1{\mathrm{null}\left( #1 \right)}$
$\def\dim#1{\mathrm{dim}\left( #1 \right)}$
$\def\null#1{\mathrm{null}\left( #1 \right)}$
$\def\tinybox#1{\mbox{\tiny #1}}$
$\def\range#1{\mathrm{range}\left( #1 \right)}$

$1_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $e_j$, so $Ee_j$ is equal to the $j$th column of $E$ and the expression you have written is
$$\pdv{ f}{ X_{ij}}=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^m a_k X_{kl} E_{lj} b_i$$
Lets treat $f$ as a multivariate function where the variables are the elements of the matrix $X$. The expression in the r.h.s. contains the term $a_i X_{ij} E_{jj} b_i $; we can only get this term in the partial derivative if $f=\frac{1}{2} a_i X_{ij} E_{jj }X_{ij} b_i+\ldots$. We also have
$$
\sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\neq i}}^n \sum_{\substack{ l=1 \\ l \neq j}}^m a_k X_{kl} E_{lj} b_i
$$
which is the partial derivative w.r.t. $X_{ij}$ of,
$$\sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\neq i}}^n \sum_{\substack{ l=1 \\ l \neq j}}^m a_k X_{kl} E_{lj} X_{ij} b_i$$
So we can write,
$$
 f = \frac{1}{2} a_i X_{ij} E_{jj }X_{ij} b_i
 + \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\neq i}}^n \sum_{\substack{l=1 \\ l\neq j}}^m a_k X_{kl} E_{lj} X_{ij} b_i + g
 $$
where $g$ is not a function of $X_{ij}$.

Now lets derive $\pdv{ f}{ X_{pr}}$: $\frac{1}{2} a_i X_{ij} E_{jj }X_{ij} b_i$ does not contain $X_{pr}$; the second term is a linear function of $X_{pr}$ so we get $a_p E_{rj} X_{ij} b_i$; the third term is $\pdv{ g}{ X_{pr}}$. So we must have,
$$
 \pdv{ f}{ X_{pr}}= a_p E_{rj} X_{ij} b_i+ \pdv{ g}{ X_{pr}}
 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^m a_k X_{kl} E_{lr} b_p
 $$
The $X_{ij}$ term on the r.h.s. has coefficient $a_i E_{jr} b_p$; we have already established that $g$ is not a function of $X_{ij}$. So we must have $a_p E_{rj} b_i = a_i E_{jr} b_p$; this is possible only if $a=b$ and $E_{rj}=E_{jr}$ (i.e. the matrix is symmetric). So unless these conditions hold the expression you wrote does not have an antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\h{\tfrac12\,}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{Sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\skew#1{\op{Skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Before jumping into matrix variables, consider the easier vector problem
$$ \grad fx = Mx \qif f = \h x^TMx $$
The anti-derivative in this case is a $\sf Quadratic\ Form\,$ and $M$ is a symmetric matrix.

Now take @greg's first formula, drop the indices, and [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) it $ \LR{\,x=\vc X} $
$$\eqalign{
\grad fX &= \LR{ba^TXE} \qif
\grad fx = \LR{E^T\k ba^T}x \\
}$$
This gets us back to the vector case, wherein the coefficient matrix must be symmetric.
Let's check
$$\eqalign{
\LR{E^T\k ba^T}^T
 = \LR{E\k ba^T}^T
 = \LR{E^T\k ab^T}
 \ne \LR{E^T\k ba^T}
}$$
Since $E$ is symmetric this **almost** works, but the $ba^T$ term is not symmetric, unless $b=a$ (as others have pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write the desired derivative is
$$\eqalign{
\def\b{\beta} \def\a{\alpha} \def\h{\tfrac12}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ij}} &= \big(ba^TXE\big)_{ij} \\
}$$
Consider the function
$$\eqalign{
f &= \h{\rm Trace}\big(ba^TXEX^T\big) \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ij}} &= \h\big(ba^TXE + ab^TXE\big)_{ij} \\
}$$
Then a derivative of the desired form occurs if $\,b=a,\,$ as you noted.

Also as you noted, if $\,n={\tt1},\,$ then it is easy to find a function which produces the desired derivative because $i$ gets fixed at $i={\tt1},\,$ the vectors $(a,b)\,$ collapse to scalars $(\a,\b)\,$ and $X$ to a row vector $x^T$
$$\eqalign{
f &= \h{\rm Trace}\big(\a\b\,x^TEx\big) \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}^T} &= \big(\b\a\,x^TE\big)_{j} \\
}$$

---

If you replace the outer product $ba^T$ by a general matrix $A,\,$ then
$$\eqalign{
f &= \h{\rm Trace}\big(AXEX^T\big) \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ij}} &= \h\big(AXE + A^TXE^T\big)_{ij} \\
}$$
If both $A\ {\rm and}\ E$ are symmetric then you get a nice anti-derivative for
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ij}} &= \big(AXE\big)_{ij}
}$$
otherwise I don't **think** the anti-derivative exists.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that there is no $f$ such that $\frac{d f}{d X_{ij}} = \big(ba^TXE\big)_{ij}$ for general $a$ and $b$?